# Windows8 Enterprise evaluation is not loading on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS VirtualBox(NX bit Disabled)

Tags: windows-8, ubuntu-12.04, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Insprion 1525 laptop loaded with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

My BIOS version is A16(10/16/2008).

Processor : Intel Core2 Duo

When I tried to load Windows8 Enterprise evaluation on the Virtualbox, I got following error.

```
Your PC needs to restart.
Please hold down the power button.
Error Code: 0x0000005D
Parameters:
0x03060F0D
0x756E6547
0x49656e69
0x6C65746E
```

I googled for a solution and found that Windows 8 requires NX bit enabled (XD in Intel architecture) hardware which is not enabled in my system. I found an option of "CPU XD support" under security tab. It is enabled by default. Still I am facing the same issue. Is this the compatibility issue of the host operating system? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The 1525 does not support intel VT-x so windows 8 will not install in virtualbox.  Even if your core2 duo supports it, there is no option to enable it in the bios.  have you used virtualbox with other Oses?

Answer (score 0):

You need VT. I had the same issue but on XP Host OS on a dell optiplex 760. But when I used VMWare instead of VBox it worked. You may want to try VMWare